# Db2 full-text search issue

Tags: db2, full-text-search

I have an issue with text search in the DB2 version 11.1 database. The database is case-insensitive. I have created a full-text index on a column of type CLOB. Now I have noticed an anomaly.

To search for a word within the text, I use the following query:

```
db2 "select id from table where CONTAINS(column,'wider')=1"
```

If I search for the word "Wider" within the following text:

"The American bar area forward, with its impressive structural counter, are united amidships with the extended lounge area, which is furnished with WIDE sofas designed to adapt to different convivial situations and sheltered by the carbon fiber hard top."

and use the query pasted above, unfortunately, and I don't understand why, the text search yields a positive result; the text contains the searched word.

If I search for the word "wide," the text search correctly yields a positive result. If I search for the word "wid," the text search correctly yields a negative result.

The issue with the word "wider" manifests similarly with other words.

Can someone explain the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Working as designed](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=indexes-search-functions)...

> The CONTAINS function searches for matches of a word or phrase and can
> be used with wildcard characters to search for substring matches in a
> manner similar to the SQL LIKE predicate and can search for exact
> string matches in a manner similar to the SQL = operator. However,
> there are key distinctions between using the CONTAINS function and
> using the SQL LIKE predicate or the = operator. The LIKE predicate and
> the = operator search for patterns in a document, while CONTAINS uses
> linguistic processing: that is, it searches for different forms of the
> search term. For example, even without using wildcard characters,
> searches for the term work also return documents containing working
> and worked.

If you want to find an exact match, use double quotes
`db2 "select id from table where CONTAINS(column,'"wider"')=1"`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was not aware of this fundamental information. Indeed, in the documentation, I found this indication: "Use quotation marks (") around your search term or phrase to have only exact matches returned." Unfortunately, the search still finds matches in the text even with quotation marks, as you suggested. How come?

Comment: Honestly, not sure.  I only ever played around with it on Db2 for IBM i and that was years ago.  I just happened to remember that the linguistic search was built in.